# Pseudo-Nmos inverter in LTSPICE

Tags: simulation, inverter, ltspice, nmos

In LTSPICE, I've built a pseudo-NMOS inverter and I've got 2 tasks to do using it.

1) I've a initial guess for Wn value of NMOS. I start the simulation with this value however, I need to optimize it and get a more precise value.

Basically, when Vol < x for some x, I need to find the minimum Wn value that satisfies this inequality.

2)Initially, nothing is connected to the output of inverter. Then, I connect a capacitor after finding my Wn value. At this point I need to find LOW-to-HIGH delay of the inverter.

I think I need a DC sweep for the first one. But don't know how to extract my value.

I have no idea for the second one though.

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To find the appropriate width for the transistor, make the width be a parameter rather than a fixed value. Then run a dc sweep where that parameter is swept through a reasonable range of values. Check the plot of Vout to find the value of width that satisfies your requirements.

For rise/fall times and delays you need to use a transient analysis. You will specify a voltage source for the input voltage, probably using the PULSE or PWL style of voltage source. Observe the plot of the output voltage to determine the timing parameters of interest. The cursors can be helpful here. If you want to really do it right, use a `.measure` command to automate the measurement.

Note that it is my intention to give you some hints to get you started rather than providing a tutorial on LTspice. There are already many good examples in the LTspice users group and in the documentation.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. How can I set Wn as a paramater though ? I tried right clicking my NMOS and trying to write {x} in the Wn box. Didn't work though.

Comment: What _exactly_ do you mean by "didn't work"?

Comment: "effective channel width less than 0". I guess my syntax is wrong ?

Comment: Okay I got the second part done. Still struggling with setting Wn as an unknown parameter though.

Answer (score 0):

What you need is the .STEP  command, this is explained well in the LT spice documentation. A DC sweep sweeps voltage.

in your spice deck, you call by using:
- .STEP param X list 0.2u 0.4u etc. etc.

Where previously you had to define X in your component list, in your example you would substitute X into the width parameter.  This is of course only a rough guideline just searching the [excellent resources](http://www.linear.com/solutions/1831) available at linear technologies website.

Another alternative is to use Monte Carlo analysis but that's much more complex situation and what you'd enquired about.